# Can a Raspberry Pi 3 play videos from Ustream?

Tags: video, internet, performance, streaming

I am thinking about purchasing a Raspberry Pi 3 to stream video from Ustream in a web browser. Is a Pi 3 running Raspbian capable of doing this without choppy video? Does it have the necessary codecs?

I am new to Raspberry Pi so I am not sure what it is capable of doing.